# Android Studio crash and i lose my key store

Tags: android, sign

With android studio, i generate a signed apk with the wizard... but one day this one crash, and when i try to sign it again tell me "cannot find key ".
I have my fingerprint save.
There is anyway to sign it again for upload the version in the market?
because if i create a new .jks dosen't works.

Comment: tahnks! i would say something like this, but let's try it again: i think i have the debug.keystore than i put for the first upload, but i generate a new keypath with the wizard and i always use that, after the crash dosen't work anymore and i don't set a route, so i couldn't find what happen with the ".jks" than i generate

Comment: Somebody say off site backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the original key to publish this application updates on market. It's also impossible to recover key from it's fingerprint. Check your disk for .keystore files and try to find where did you saved your original one.

Comment: where it is saved when you create a new key store path, and you dosen't select a route? i search my .keystore and all of them are old ones, i try the lastone and market get stuck on processing

Comment: this is saved where you save it - you have to manually enter the path for newly created key. The default ones are saved in the .android folder of current user.

Comment: it was saved on ~\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio\ lol without extension, just the name like i set... be carefull with that! THANKS EVRYONE